# Installer for windows 7/8 driver 

Tags: windows, installation, driver

I have a .inf file and a .sys file and a couple of dll's.
to install the driver manually i do from elevated command prompt :

```
devcon install driver.inf HID\driver
```

I want some pointers on how to make the installer for this driver . 
Thanks.

PS: I am a complete noob when it comes to things related to drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a simple installer based on NSIS that copies the files and executes the command . Also devcon binary is not redistibutable but we can copy parts of the devcon source that we need in order to create a specific driver installer binary.